# Correct translation for complex sentence

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

I need to translate some from russian into english. 
english is foreign to me, so I asked for a help.
My english is poor, But thranslated text seems to be wrong.
For example:

> Боевой пропуск, позволяющий получать больше различных наград

translated into

> Battle Pass to get even more different rewards

1) I'm shure, that words before "to get something" must be some sort of action. In result, "do some action" to get "something". But "Battle Pass" is NOT an action.

2) the word "different" changes meaning of sentense:
"more rewards" = "больше наград".
"even more rewards" = "ещё больше наград".
BUT
"more different rewards" = "более разнообразных наград".
"even more different rewards" = "ещё более разнообразных наград".
The meaning of the original text was "quantity" of rewards
The meaning of transtatet text is "difference" between rewards.

Am i right?

Comment: Can you give some context? Without none this sound like it is about a concept of "battle pass", which is related to the video game series "Battlefield".

Comment: that is correct. it IS a concept of "battle pass", which is related to the video game series like "Battlefield" and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would translate this into:

```
Battle Pass, which lets you earn even more rewards
```

1 - I imagine the reason the translation came out this way is "pass" being a verb as well as a noun.

2 - Russian word "различный" often confuses automatic translation (at least in my experience), because it is often used without much reason to do so. The appropriate translation is "various" rather than "different", however, it still feels needless to me. You could use it, but I would leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

**получать больше различных наград** - **`to get/receive/obtain/win a greater number of (different) / (different kinds of) rewards`**